# query runs fine in mysql and php but not in java

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have the following mysql query in PHP and it works fine.

```
$strUpdate = "INSERT INTO  `batchfolder`.`newbatch` (`BatchID` ,`Batch` ,`barcode` ,`PG`)VALUES (NULL ,  '',  '1',  '')";
```

and is also fine when i run it directly in database.

However when I run it in java,

```
 try {
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
          Statement st = conn.createStatement();
          st.execute("INSERT INTO  `batchfolder`.`newbatch` (`BatchID` ,`Batch` ,`barcode` ,`PG`)VALUES (NULL ,  '',  '1',  '')");            
          st.close();
}
```

It gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Field 'Pre' doesn't have a default value
```

Pre is the the next row in the database and it does not have a default value.

My question is, then how does this query run fine in mysql and php.

P.S BatchID is an `int(10) autoincremented` value in newbatch.

This is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newbatch` (
  `BatchID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Batch` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Ly` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PG` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Pre` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Flu` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `FluID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateCreated` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BatchID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FluID` (`FluID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1000160 ;
```

Comment: can you show the tables structure?

Comment: `show create table newbatch` would help.

Comment: I get a sense that your just now learning Java, look into using prepared statement.

Comment: @BenSchro10 Yes I'm new to java. I used it before but haven't used it much until recently. I am aware of prepared statement too. but i guess its gonna throw the same error..

Comment: I just tried executing your query in phpMyAdmin after using your `CREATE` statement to make the table -- it didn't work (same error you're getting). I think something else must be going on in order for it to work in PHP.

Comment: I tried it again in mysql (phpmyadmin) and it works. :-(

Comment: Once you get the SQL issue figured out, check out using prepared statement and if your bold enough move forward looking into ORM's and stored procedures. Cross reference using these techniques in the fight against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure this actually runs in PHP? You may just not be seeing the error message.

Try this again with `display_errors = 'on'` and `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`
This is a SQL error, it doesn't depend on the driver. The driver just displays the message to you.

**UPDATE:**
It looks like Java is turning off MySQL's strict mode for some reason. The only thing that (to my knowledge) should be able to cause this behavior is MySQL strict mode being off.

> If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit
>   default value for the column data type.

You can check the mode that your server is running on by `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`. Try that in both Java and PHP. If the results differ then that's your answer.

**UPDATE2:** [Jep!](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24526)

Comment: also runs fine in the database

Comment: And is it the same MySQL server in both times?

Comment: I tried doing what u suggested. both php and java didn't produce anything.

Comment: May not be global but session mode then.
`SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;`

Comment: I think this answer is correct. Your installation of MySQL must have strict mode disabled, but Java, unlike PHP and MySQL, forces strict mode. Check your my.ini file.

Comment: makes a lot of sense.. I shouldn't be working with strict mode off !!

Answer (score 1):

Looked at your table definition, you have Pre defined as not null, but you didnt specify a value for it in the insert, so it should show an error proper.

Comment: I know it should. It doesn't in PHP and database

Comment: Im curious, if you have defined the column as NOT NULL, and your insert statement doesnt specify a value, then what the heck is PHP putting in as a value?

Comment: @BenSchro10 read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: Thanks @Cypher, its my opinion though that even with that mysql option the SQL statement itself is still invalid, so im going to guess its a driver issue probably, just rewrite the query so it correct, thats ultimately the right thing to do since we have the table design off the bat.

Comment: @Ankur if your good with a Zero going in then just add it to the statement, do the same for the other columns defined as NOT NULL but without default values and im guessing it should work.

Comment: @BenSchro10 I'm with u. I rewrote the query and its all fine. I was curious that why was my incorrect query working all this time without throwing an error. For the first time, I'm unhappy that something is working (when it shouldn't).

Comment: With that option, the statement is valid. Java just ignores that option (see that Jep in my answer).

Comment: Well when you start talking about portability of the application against databases other than MySQL it becomes a very important issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have several database fields that are 'NOT NULL', so you must specify these in your INSERT statement.   I couldn't imagine how this would work in PHP either.

Comment: Ever heard of SQL modes? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html